# Wordpress add action and echo the value in template

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to get the vendor e-mail from the order_id from a woocommerce order checkout on thank you page. There i would like to echo the email address of the vendors, which sold the products in order to get in touch with them. However, i have difficulties to echo the value(emails).

on the functions page I use:

```
add_action( 'thankyou_get_vendor_email', 'get_vendor_email' ); //

function get_vendor_email ( $order_id ){
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $product_name = $item->get_name();
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
        $vendor_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $product_id );
        $vendor_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $product_id );
        $vendor = get_userdata( $vendor_id );
        $email = $vendor->user_email;
    }

    echo $email;
}
```

and on the template page I use:

```
<?php  echo do_action( 'thankyou_get_vendor_email' ); ?>
```

Comment: You seem to be missing something. Also, any error messages? Any thing in the logs?

Comment: no I don't get any error message, but if I change add_action( 'thankyou_get_vendor_email', 'get_vendor_email' ); to add_action( 'add_action( 'thankyou_get_vendor_email', 'get_vendor_email' );', 'get_vendor_email' ); then the value (email) is display at the end of the page

Comment: Describe the problem.  "I have difficulties".  What difficulties? Does anything echo? What happens if you `var_dump($items);` - do you see data on the screen then? Or `var_dump($order_id);`? Is the hook being called at all?  Also - your `action` accepts an argument for the `$order_id`, but your `do_action` does not send the order_id.  What happens if you do `do_action('thankyou_get_vendor_email', $order_id);`